# Kafka Tool not starting at all - Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: java, ubuntu, apache-kafka

I allready look to previous similar questions, but none applies to my case. The most similar question asked was on a Ubuntu 20.04 which didn't have any answers before the question was deleted...

I recently installed Ubuntu 19.10 on my PC, after installing most of the essentials i need for development i installed kafkatool from the official site, the first time run without problems.

It was days later, after i try to start kafka tool it does not start at all. When i check the `error.log` inside the kafkatool2 folder, there is no error:

```
26/Jun/2020 16:54:24.563 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - Starting application : Kafka Tool
26/Jun/2020 16:54:24.564 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - Version : 2.0.7
26/Jun/2020 16:54:24.565 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - Built : Jan 11, 2020
26/Jun/2020 16:54:24.565 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - user.home : /home/marcelo
26/Jun/2020 16:54:24.565 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - user.dir : /home/marcelo/kafkatool2
26/Jun/2020 16:54:24.565 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - os.name : Linux
26/Jun/2020 16:54:24.565 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - java.runtime.version : 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1~19.10-b09
26/Jun/2020 16:54:24.565 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - max memory=5326 MB
26/Jun/2020 16:54:24.565 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - available processors=6
26/Jun/2020 16:54:24.565 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - java.security.auth.login.config=null
26/Jun/2020 16:54:24.583 INFO  com.kafkatool.common.ExternalDecoderManager - Finding plugins in directory /home/marcelo/kafkatool2/plugins
26/Jun/2020 16:54:24.595 INFO  com.kafkatool.common.ExternalDecoderManager - Found files in plugin directory, count=1
26/Jun/2020 16:54:24.604 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - Loading user settings    
26/Jun/2020 16:54:24.840 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - Loading server group settings
26/Jun/2020 16:54:24.844 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - Loading server connection settings
```

The log ends at Loading server connection settings

I already try to:

- uninstall, then re-install
- trying to start from terminal (as my user and sudo)
- trying to start from app launcher

I'm running on a Ubuntu 19.10, my Java version is:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1~19.10-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
```

if it helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem.  I managed to fix it by installing Oracle JDK 8_261 (latest 8 as of today) and then editing the `kafkatool` file to explicitly use that version (see the first few lines of the file):

```
INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_261"
```

hope it works for you.

Comment: thank you very much! Marking this answer as the solution

Answer (score 11):

If options from other answers do not help, then you can simply remove settings directory(they may be corrupted and after next start will be recreated):

```
/home/{USERNAME}/.kafkatool2 (hidden directory)
```

Sometimes it helps.

Comment: This did the job for me. Thanks!

Comment: In fact you have to remove only `/home/{USERNAME}/.kafkatool2/connections.xml`. This file is corrupted

Answer (score 0):

downgrade your open jdk to 1.8.0_242 and run keytool with it.